# Np.where function

Tags: numpy, gps, location, where-clause

I've got a little problem understanding the where function in numpy.
The ‘**times**’ array contains the discrete epochs at which GPS measurements exist (rounded to the nearest second). 
The ‘**locations**’ array contains the discrete values of the latitude, longitude and altitude of the satellite interpolated from 10 seconds intervals to 1 second intervals at the ‘times’ epochs. 
The ‘**tracking**’ array contains an array for each epoch in ‘times’ (array within an array). The arrays have 5 columns and 32 rows. The 32 rows correspond to the 32 satellites of the GPS constellation. The 0th row corresponds to the 1st satellite, the 31st to the 32nd. The columns contain the following (in order): is the satellite tracked (0), is L1 locked (1), is L2 locked (2), **is L1 unexpectedly lost (3), is L2 unexpectedly lost (4)**.

**We need to find all the unexpected losses and put them in an array so we can plot it on a map.**

What we tried to do is:

```
i = 0
with np.load(r’folderpath\%i.npz' %i) as oneday_data: #replace folderpath with your directory
    times = oneday_data['times']
    locations = oneday_data['locations']
    tracking = oneday_data['tracking']
A = np.where(tracking[:][:][4] ==1)
```

This should give us all the positions of the losses. With this indices it is easy to get the right locations. But it keeps returning useless data.

Can someone help us?

Comment: Could you make a simple example with a small array `tracking` . What do you get with that example and what do you want to obtain with that example?

Comment: To expand on the comment above, instead of describing your data with words, write a small representative sample sample with code. e.g. `times = np.array([1.0, 2.5, 3.0, 4.7])`

Comment: What's the purpose of the `[:][:]`?   Is `tracking[:][:][4]` meaningful data?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your dual slices.  Further, having an array of arrays could lead to weird problems (I assume you mean an object array of 2D arrays).

So I think you need to `dstack` `tracking` into a 3D array, then do `where` on that.  If the array is already 3D, then you can skip the `dstack` part.  This will get the places where `L2 is unexpectedly lost`, which is what you did in your example:

```
tracking3d = np.dstack(tracking)
A0, A2 = np.where(tracking3d[:, 4, :]==1)
```

`A0` is the position of the `1` along axis `0` (satellite), while `A2` is the position of the same `1` along axis `2` (time epoch).

If the values of `tracking` can only be `0` or `1`, you can simplify this by just doing `np.where(tracking3d[:, 4, :])`.

You can also roll the axes back into the configuration you were using (0: time epoch, 1: satellite, 2: tracking status)

```
tracking3d = np.rollaxis(np.dstack(tracking), 2, 0)
A0, A1 = np.where(tracking3d[:, :, 4]==1)
```

If you want to find the locations where L1 or L2 are unexpectedly lost, you can do this:

```
tracking3d = np.rollaxis(np.dstack(tracking), 2, 0)
A0, A1, _ = np.where(tracking3d[:, :, 3:]==1)
```

In this case it is the same, except there is a dummy variable `_` used for the location along the last axis, since you don't care whether it was lost for L1 or L2 (if you do care, you could just do `np.where` independently for each axis).